# how to get a class to take in another classes parameters?

Tags: c++, class

> I want to have my grid class constructor to take in drivers_location parameters , but it keeps giving me these errors.
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgUUZ.jpg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


class drivers_location {
public:
    drivers_location() = default;
    drivers_location(string name, float xx, float yy){
x = xx;
y = yy;
name = driver_name;
}





private:
    float x{};
    float y{};
    string driver_name;




};
class grid {

public:
    grid() = default;
    grid(drivers_location(string name, float xx, float yy));


private:



};
int main() {
    drivers_location p;
    float pointx{ 2.0 };
    float pointy{ 3.0 };
grid m[5];
     m[0] = { {"abdul" , pointx, pointy }};


}
```

I want the grid to take in parameters of drivers_location without using inheritance if that's possible

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This `drivers_location(string name, float xx, float yy)` is not what you  think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for declaring a constructor takes argument of type `driver_location` is as shown below. Note that you don't have to specify the 2 parameters of `driver_location` when defining the constructor for `grid` that has a parameter of type `driver_location`.

```
class grid {

public:
    grid() = default;
    //---vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---->this is how we specify that this ctor has a parameter of type drivers_location
    grid(drivers_location){
       //add your code here
    }
    private:

};
```

I would also recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).